# TOC with auto-spacing for roman enumeration

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am trying to set up a TOC where chapters are enumerated with roman numerals. However, when I get to VIII, say, this overlaps with the chapter title. I can fix this by adding a space before every roman numeral in the TOC, but I was trying to figure out if there is a fancier way to do this, so that text auto-spaces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsection}% <section>
  [1.55 cm]% <left>
  {\small}% <above-code>
  {\thecontentslabel. \hspace{3pt}}% <numbered-entry-format>; you could also use {\thecontentslabel. } to show the numbers
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {}% <filler-page-format>
  [ --- \ ]% <separator>
  []% <end>
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% Display up to \subsection in ToC

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10 pt}

%\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution with `titletoc`. You shouldn't use both `tocloft` and `titletoc`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[rightlabels]{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{1.5em}
\titlecontents{chapter}
[2em] %
{\bigskip}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}\hspace{0.333em}}%\thecontentslabel
{\hspace*{-2em}}
{\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]%\hfill

\titlecontents{section}% <section>
[2.35em]% <left>
{\small\contentsmargin{1.5em}}% <above-code>
{\thecontentslabel.\hspace{3pt}}% <numbered-entry-format>; you could also use {\thecontentslabel. } to show the numbers
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\enspace\titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}~\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\titlecontents*{subsection}% <section>
[3.23em]% <left>
{\footnotesize\contentsmargin{0em}}% <above-code>
{\thecontentslabel. \hspace{3pt}}% <numbered-entry-format>; you could also use {\thecontentslabel. } to show the numbers
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{}% <filler-page-format>
[ --- \ ]% <separator>
[]% <end>
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% Display up to \subsection in ToC

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter the First}
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}
\section{A last section with subsections}
\subsection{A nice subsection}
\subsection{An enthralling subsection}
\subsection{The subsection you’ve always dreamt of}
\chapter{Chapter the Second}
\chapter{Chapter the Third}
\chapter{Chapter the Fourth}
\chapter{Chapter the Fifth}
\chapter{Chapter the Sixth}
\setcounter{page}{200}
\chapter{Chapter the Seventh}
\section{Yet another section}
\chapter{Epilogue}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This style is much easier to do with `titletoc` than with `tocloft`. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks for having edited. I'm afraid my typo was of the Freudian kind (`toclost`:o)).

Comment: :D Indeed.....!

Comment: OK, so I should replace all the lines of my MWE (which are part of a much larger file) with your lines, correct? Your subsection numbering seems to be continuing the section number, perhaps that is unintended.

Comment: Question: two digit page numbers are right aligning correctly, but when I get to three digit page numbers, they appear outside the margin you set. Is this normal?

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: That's a problem of setting another value for `\contentsmargin` (this sets the *right* margin). I've modified the code so you can go without problem up to 9999pages (will you? ;o)). On the other hand the subsection numbering is OK. It's me who changed in the code the starting point of the numbering  for alignment testing purposes, and in the new version, I removed it. Last point: I slightly simplified the code, and shifted page numbers for sections to the left, as I find it more pleasing, aesthetically. Of course, this suits my personal taste, and it's easy to change back.

Comment: Thank you, Bernard. Its about 200 pages, so we're safe for the moment. ;) As a final request, what's the part of the code where I can set the right margin of the subsections and the chapters to be right aligned?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: The rightmargin is set for all section levels by  \contentsmargin, so we can't play with this parameter. You want the  right margin of the subsections to be aligned on the document right margin (vertical rule on the right in the image)?

Comment: @Bernard Correct. Note that in your previous versions the section page was aligned with the chapter page in the TOC. You can see that in your previous screenshots. In the new versions the Roman. Chapter alignment seems to be acting up too. I hope I'm not coming off a too picky, just letting you know these might be unintended modifications.

Comment: I know. Do you prefer this previous way? I thought it was nice to make the chapter pages stand out, but it's easy to revert to the old version.